# Can i Use FTP for accessing remote Folder and Files

Tags: .net, wpf, ftp

I have set of excel files in folder in remote server. And one WPF application is running on my local machine. Now i want to able to look at files in the remote folder and download. How to achieve this?

Can i Use FTP for this?
If Possible How?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Oh, come on, have you googled for your own question?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  Here's a nice [example](http://www.rixsoft.co.uk/2011/04/easy-ftp-in-wpf-and-net/).  And [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx).

```
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(destinationoffile, FileMode.Create);
FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
long cl = response.ContentLength;
int bufferSize = 2048;
int readCount;
float perc = 0;
float result = 0;
float totalread = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
while (readCount > 0)
{
         totalread += readCount;
         result = totalread / fileSize;
         perc = result * 100;
         progress.Value = perc; // this is a progressbar on my screen so may show error for you
         outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
         readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

responseStream.Close();
response.Close();
outputStream.Close(); // keeps file open if not closed
```

Comment: "Easy FTP in WPF and .Net" --- just curious, what is WPF-specific in this code? Btw, streams will not be disposed in case of any exception thrown in that sample. Wouldn't recommend it as a *nice example*.

Comment: This is the type of answer that can be found by simply using Google. So I provided the official documentation (MSDN) and an example since MSDN is sometime a bit bad with examples. FtpWebRequest is available in WPF so I don't get what your gripe is.  If he asked how to add two numbers in WPF would you complain that the answer "c = a + b;" isn't "WPF-specific"?

Comment: And it's pretty common knowledge that examples typically don't provide robust error handling.  It just obscures the issue.  If you want to go add full and complete error handling to every example on SO then be my guest.

Comment: it is not a hard work to add `using` and pair of curly braces

Comment: Instead of complaining about a minor point by commenting on an answer you think needs some improvement, just use the edit link.  That's what it's for.  You have more than enough rep to do so.